# Normal for external SanDisk SSD 2T taking over 2 minutes to access files? Use not to

Tags: macos, ssd, external-disk

So I have a MBP 16" 2019 on Monterey 12.13.1 and using Sandisk external SSD drive partitioned Mac OS journaled and Windows ExFAT.  Up to now when mounting the drive all loaded pretty quickly, matter of seconds.  I last used the drive 4 days ago for a time machine backup.  When I plugged it in today to move some emails to it, the drive and both partitions showed in finder in about 3 seconds, but when I went to access the Mac partition it took over 2 minutes to load.

I then ejected the drive and remounted - same - over 2 minutes to load the Mac part.

How can I tell why the access time has changed to be over 2 minutes?  Also I did First Aid on the Mac partition which took 10 minutes to complete.  Here are the results:

[image: results]

Here is the drive info:

[image: drive info]

The only other odd behavior I notice  is that before today when ejecting the drive I would pick one partition and eject it then answer "Yes" to eject all drives question.  Today, I no longer get that question every time  when ejecting.

Here is some more info:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

[image: SSD info]

I also tried this, "wmmbp@MacBook-Pro ~ % sudo fs_usage |grep SanDisk Mac
grep: Mac: No such file or directory"

But it did not work.....

EDIT:  I tried to insert text but there is a limit and this exceeded it.  Hope this attached .jpg works....  No good.  Its text and I cant see how to attach a .pdf and the .jpg/.heic exceeds the limit and I cant reduce it.  Its 60 pages of output.

Edit// Added :EXTREME SSD" System Report. Also, added the grep file output. The Windows Partition comes up right away and files are accessible when mounting the usb.  Its the Apple partition that takes a long time now for some reason...

[Diagnostic output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dyl7-1kP-l_L1F8hjTJQPCznbTi_ixwu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have seen external disk enclosures fail even though if the actual disk was fine.

Comment: what is "external disk enclosure" ?

Comment: The extra bits that converts a plain SSD or traditional harddisk, to an external harddisk that can be connected with e.g. USB.

Comment: thanks. still trying to figure this out....

Comment: instead of: grep SanDisk Mac you need to write: grep "SanDisk Mac", ie. you need to quote the text you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Two minutes for a `fsck` isn’t abnormal, so the slow mount usually means the last eject wasn’t clean or the file system needs extra scrutiny. You can test this by running the check later by timing it.

If you feel everything else is normal, next thing I would check is what link speed was negotiated for that storage in system information. Open bout this Mac and select system information. Look up USB details for the device.

Checking iops during the first aid might be worth the effort. Look at activity monitor for that disk.

Third thing is I would measure the temperature of the drive (without the case if possible) via [infrared tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09MFFYBQJ).

Comment: Thank you - will do. Although I’m away from drive , traveling, and won’t be able to  ck for a few weeks.    CAn you tell me how to ck iops and link speed?  I do have temp infrared…. Thank you. Sorry for brevity on phone.

Comment: Hey bmike- can you tell me where to ck link speed pls?  Also, I dont see the disk in act monitor to ck iops.  How can I select disk in activity monitor ?  Temp of drive while being accessed varies from 77 - 101F.  w/ case.  Any help appreciated - still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Hi @Stumped look at my edit today to the post for details on system information app. Those temperatures seem normal. Start a new question on using activity monitor so I can address that new topic with pictures, please.

Comment: Looking for how to attach info- 60 pages of output, in your edit. Don’t see, sorry. Also, +2minutes is not fsck but time it’s talking for files to show after connecting usb….

Comment: If you have questions on how the site works, we have a place for that on [meta]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dyl7-1kP-l_L1F8hjTJQPCznbTi_ixwu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Saw your post re: help.... Thank you - appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Such a long delay is usually an indication that the file system is getting checked for errors. That happens if the disk wasn't fully unmounted (ejected), leaving some data in a state that causes the check next time you mount it.

You may also be able to find some information about the check in the Console log (search for the name of your volume or for the command `fsck_apfs`.

Comment: Thank you - will do. Although I’m away from drive , traveling, and won’t be able to  ck for a few weeks.  How do I get to the console log please??  Thank you.

Comment: so I do not see how to select this external disk in console.  Can you tell me how pls?  I put some screen shots above of what I tried bit w/o knowing if its what's you meant??  Any help appreciated - still trying to figure this out.

Comment: When looking at the logs in Console.app, select either the top (your Mac's name) or "system.log", then use the top right search field.

Comment: I have output from grep but can attach as exceeds file size as.jpg and I see no way to attach .txt or .pdf.  If I edit and insert text, it exceeds character limit....   How d o I get the info into this thread??

Comment: in console app, when I select my Mac or system log and search for "fsck_apfs", nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0):

checking the drive for errors showed no issues and came back clean.  Apparently there was some sort of drive error as I move all the files to another drive and reformatted it and now all is back to as it was before the issue.